# How to Split a string by adding colon to that in Hive?

Tags: regex, string, split, hive, hiveql

I need to split a string 125416 with colons

For example

Given String = 125436 convert to 12:54:36

Answer (score 0):

Use regex. This replaces each two characters with these characters + colon:

```
select regexp_replace('125436','(..)', '$1:')
```

Result:

```
12:54:36:
```

This is not exactly what is required, it contains extra colon. You can use negative look ahead `(?!$)` to exclude last pair from being replaced:

```
select regexp_replace('125436','(..)(?!$)', '$1:')
```

Result:

```
12:54:36
```

Or the same using group 0, a bit shorter:

```
select regexp_replace('125436','..(?!$)', '$0:')
```